# Step Plugin Development : How to list custom variables inside textVar() input?

Tags: java, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-cde

I'm trying to develop a `step plugin` using `Pentaho`,

I used `textVar()` Input for listing the variables.

the problem is that the custom variables that created from the previous step aren't listed, so i tried to used `environmentSubstitute(${var})` inside my code for fetching the variable's value, and no thing effected !.

so please guide me to the right way for listing the custom variables that created using the previous steps , for listing it inside `textVar()` input inside my custom step plugin.

Comment: I suggest you to post the question on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/kettle-developers
and when you figure out how to manage it, share with us please.

Comment: I joined the group but i don't have a permission to add a topic yet. by the way i found this method but i don't know how it work, i tried something like this `fieldSubstitute(meta.getField(), data.outputRowMeta, getRow())` but it gives me the field name too without replacing it with it's value. i think that i have something wrong with the passed parameters. so any Help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many days of testing , I succeeded of listing previous field names using the follwoing :

```
Combo wField = new Combo();
            String[] inputFields = transMeta.getPrevStepFields(stepname).getFieldNames();
            Arrays.sort(inputFields);

            for (String fName : inputFields) {
                wField.add(fName);
            }
```

That's all :)